# UsingR package in R is not loading properly

Tags: r

> install.packages("UsingR")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/akshay/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/UsingR_2.0-5.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 2076955 bytes (2.0 MB)
>   downloaded 2.0 MB

package ‘UsingR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
enter code here

I installed the UsingR Package as shown above.
But when I try to load it I am getting error in the last line.

```
> library(UsingR)
```

Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: HistData
Loading required package: Hmisc
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: survival
Error: package ‘Formula’ required by ‘Hmisc’ could not be found

The father.son data set is supposed to be in this package. But I am not getting it.

```
> data(father.son)
```

Warning message:
In data(father.son) : data set ‘father.son’ not found

Can someone please point out the error.

Comment: "Error: package ‘Formula’ required by ‘Hmisc’ could not be found"

Comment: Yeah that is the error. But I am supposed to get father.son data set with UsingR Package

Comment: But why do you expect to be able to access the data set in the UsingR package, when the package is not loaded due to the error?

Comment: Can you please tell me what that error exactly is, as in why is the package not loading properly?

Answer (score 5):

Try to install package with dependencies

```
install.packages("UsingR", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I resolved the problem installing Hmisc package:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

Then I reload the UsingR package

```
library(UsingR)
```

Then I can use all the data

```
data(father.son)
```